# Why is filecmp.cmp slow for huge files even when its 'shallow' parameter is True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-comparison

I wrote a Python script to compare files in two directories, using `filecmp.cmp`. It works, but just now I tried running it for a collection of huge files. It was very slow.

The documentation says that when the `shallow` parameter is true (which it is, by default), `filecmp.cmp` should only compare the `os.stat` results.

The script ran much faster for another big collection of `jpg` files. I am wondering why the file size is having a larger effect than the number of files as if it checks `os.stat` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the documentation for the `shallow` parameter is misleading*. Passing `shallow = True` does not necessarily prevent the `filecmp.cmp` function from comparing the contents of the files. If your files are the same size but have different `mtime`s, their contents will still be checked.

You can see the implementation of `cmp` in your Python installation, or you can look at the (current as of this moment) source in the [Python source repository](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c8315bac6a8/Lib/filecmp.py).

Here are the relevant bit of `cmp`:

```
def cmp(f1, f2, shallow=True):
    # long docstring removed

    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
    s2 = _sig(os.stat(f2))
    if s1[0] != stat.S_IFREG or s2[0] != stat.S_IFREG:
        return False
    if shallow and s1 == s2:
        return True
    if s1[1] != s2[1]:
        return False

    # rest of function, which calls a helper to do the actual file contents comparisons
```

The `_sig` helper function returns a tuple of values extracted from the `stat` data structure for a file. The tuple values are the file type, the file size, and its `mtime` (usually the last time the file contents were modified).

The tests I included in the code excerpt try to quickly determine if two files are the same based on those pieces of metadata. If either file is not a "regular" file (because it's a directory, or special system file), they're considered unequal. Also, if they're not the same size, they cannot possibly equal.

What the `shallow` parameter does is allow a quick positive test. If `shallow` is true and the files have the same size and `mtime`, `filecmp.cmp` will assume the files are equal.

What I suspect is happening in your program is that your current directory has a number of files that are exactly the same size (perhaps because of very similar contents, or because the file size is fixed by the data format). Your previous data sets did not have as many same-sized files, so your code was able to quickly rule them out.

* I think `filecmp.cmp`'s docstring is so misleading that it indicates a bug (either because it doesn't describe the behavior properly, or because the actual implementation is incorrect and should be fixed to match the docs). And it looks like I'm not alone. [Here is a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1234674) on this issue, though it hasn't been updated in several years. I'll ping the bug with a link to this question and maybe somebody will work on fixing it!

Comment: tks for you info. fyi, the collection of jpeg the script ran fast is about 2G, while the collection of mts is about 24G. just ls -la the two dir of the mts for comparsion,by eye inspection most of the file are of same date and size to bytes, my script would skip file with diff names. from your inspection any condition apart from mtime diff that could run the script into content checking? from the code excerpt you quoted, it didn't show the condition to call the helper.

Comment: is filecmp.cmp pure pythonic or involve c function calling? any c speed library in python i could call to enhance performance just in case the script run into byte to byte checking?

Comment: @timeislove: The whole `filecmp` module is pure Python, though it calls C functions in other modules (like `os.stat`). You can read the full source by loading up `Lib/filecmp.py` in your Python install, or you can look at the current version [in the Python source repository](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c8315bac6a8/Lib/filecmp.py). The only thing that avoids extra file scans in `cmp` (beyond what I excerpted in my answer) is a (fairly crude) cache, but that only helps is you compare the exact same files against each other more than once.

Comment: any possible c speed file content checking? checked linux system cmp, it seems not.